# Vegan crepes that don't fall apart when turning

Tags: substitutions, vegan, crepe

When I make [crepes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%AApe) I use eggs, flour and milk for the dough and tiny amount of oil for the pan. I usually use whole wheat flower. Sometimes half-white half-whole wheat.  They always end up very thin and perfect.

Replacing milk with various liquids (soy milk, almond milk...) seems to work fine.

I would like to stop using eggs, so I made several attempts with various egg substitutes, and I can't make it work for crepes.  They always fall apart when I try to flip them.

Which ingredient would help with with that?

So far I have tried:

- The Neat Egg
- Ener G Egg Replacer
- flax
- extra oil
- applesauce
- bananas

Those all work for **thick** pancakes, but (at least not for me) for crepes.

There are questions related to replacing eggs, but are too generic:

- [How to make pancakes/crepes without eggs nor any liquids besides water?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/how-to-make-pancakes-crepes-without-eggs-nor-any-liquids-besides-water) -- not limited to vegan
- [What can I substitute for eggs in a pancake recipe?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21427/what-can-i-substitute-for-eggs-in-a-pancake-recipe) -- pancakes, not crepes
- [With what can I replace eggs?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4192/with-what-can-i-replace-eggs) -- a few answers mention pancakes, but not one mention of crepes

Comment: You could make dosas instead, which are completely vegan.  They wouldn't taste like French crepes, but they behave like them.

Comment: what style of crepe and what size?

Comment: @LightBender see ingredients I listed in the first paragraph. They have to be very thin. Size doesn't matter, but usually I use 9-inch pan

Comment: The ratio of egg:milk:flour (by volume) determine the style of crepe... French crepes are usually 2:2:1, east European crepes are usually something more like 1:4:4. You'll have better luck converting the east European style. The eggs are acting as a binder, so I use a flax seed based egg substitute mix and coconut milk and get pretty good results for small crepes. 16 inch crepes are more likely to tear.

Comment: I use slightly more than twice as much milk as flour. Using eggs, I have been able to make 16-inch ones without problem.

Comment: 1:4:4 means that you use same amount of flour as milk? That would be way too thick. If the dough is that thick, it's impossible to make thin crepes.

Comment: Keep in mind those ratios are by volume... by weight the ratio is closer to 1:2:4. I generally make ease European crepes with 250g flour, 500ml milk, and 2 eggs (plus about a 1T (13g) melted butter). I usually pour a ladle of batter that spreads on its own about 6 inches (15cm) in diameter and it spreads beautifully to a 16 inch (40cm) crepe about 1/16th inch (1.5mm) thick. If I need a paper thin crepe, I'll add an additional 250ml of milk, but I prefer to let the batter sit in the fridge overnight to allow the gluten to autolyse a bit.

Comment: I almost never weigh my ingredients. I assumed we were talking about volume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First be wary of language barrier. In some regions/countries people are making crepes and calling tham pancakes. What in US is called pancakes in some regions/countries call for buttermilk and is called (for example) "Racuchy".

Anyway - use aquafaba. Just yesterday I made some crepes with it. They are nice, soft, "rolly" and apart from a little darker color there is almost no difference in texture. There is a little in taste but if you add any flavouring agent it's not palpatable.

Comment: I added the link to wikipedia page on crepes. Hopefully that helps with language.

Comment: This: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquafaba ?

Comment: @eternal_student So the crepes is crepes, polish nalesniki. I used aquafaba from chickpeas. In the beginning you might experiment with it. AF can easily be frozen and stored for long time (it also remove a little more water). beating it before adding dry ingredients etc.